# JDK 1.7 compiler does not recognize generic class

Tags: eclipse, generics, compiler-construction, javac

I have a class which uses a class from Eclipse OSGI jar (org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar) and which is well compiled within Eclipse IDE and it's compiler. But if I try to compile this class with Ant and JDK 1.7 compiler, the compiler outputs these errors:

```
[javac] /data/ant/sw_jdk1.7/test-Java7/com.tsystems.favbg.ui.core/src/com/
        tsystems/favbg/ui/core/job/AbstractLoader.java:24: 
        error: type CopyOnWriteIdentityMap does not take parameters
[javac]     private final CopyOnWriteIdentityMap<LoaderListener, String>
            eventListenerMap = new CopyOnWriteIdentityMap<>();
```

and

```
error: cannot infer type arguments for CopyOnWriteIdentityMap;
[javac]     private final CopyOnWriteIdentityMap<LoaderListener, String> 
            eventListenerMap = new CopyOnWriteIdentityMap<>();
[javac]   reason: cannot use '<>' with non-generic class CopyOnWriteIdentityMap
```

Obviously javac does not recognize the class as using generics. But when I open it with Java Decompiler generic parameters are well recognized. 

Does anybody know this problem and have a solution?

Comment: what does javac -version say?

Comment: Could you share the definition of CopyOnWriteIdentityMap?  I'm amused that a decompiler says it has generics, since that information is lost **at compile time**.

Comment: the decompiler gives me this constructor definition (which i use): public CopyOnWriteIdentityMap(CopyOnWriteIdentityMap<? extends K, ? extends V> source). this confirms to the Indigo Java Doc.

Comment: @Rocky: I use Javac from Jdk1.7u5. Maybe I should say that I'm running this on a Linux machine, with Linux version of the Jdk from Oracle), although I do not think that the linux version of the core compiler differs from windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the problem is in the way that you are using `CopyOnWriteIdentityMap` class.  I'm assuming that you are using this class:

```
  org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.CopyOnWriteIdentityMap
```

If you look at [the javadocs](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/osgi/framework/eventmgr/CopyOnWriteIdentityMap.html), you will see that it is not a generic class.  I also get the impression (from its package location) that it is not intended to be a *general purpose* utility class.

Perhaps you are using a different version of the JAR when you are compiling in Eclipse ... one that *is* a generic class.  Either way, the compiler you are using via Ant thinks it is not generic.

Comment: Stephen: your link goes to the Helios version of CopyOnWriteIdentiyMap. In Indigo they changed the class to become generic. see http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/osgi/framework/eventmgr/CopyOnWriteIdentityMap.html

Comment: Perhaps he has the old JAR file then.  The compiler is *clearly saying* that the class isn't generic, and it's not like Sun's Java 1.7 compiler won't understand generic classes ...

Comment: "it's not like Sun's Java 1.7 compiler won't understand generic classes": yeah, that's my problem. And there is no old version of this class hanging around which the compiler sees (what i first thought).

Comment: BTW: is there a way to debug where the compiler effectively loads the classes from?

Comment: Frankly, I don't believe what you are saying.

Comment: Try the javacc -verbose flag.  According to the manual, it tells you something about each class loaded.

Comment: thanks for tip - the compiler beeing verbose exactly tells me where he is loading the class from. It is indeed the jar I expected. So, my problem stays with me.

Comment: This is a very odd compiler thing. I finally deleted all generic parameters from source code and it compiles. This is not what I expect from a compiler that understands generics. I.E: I use an anonymous inner class by implementing this: public abstract interface EventDispatcher<K, V, E>
{
  public abstract void dispatchEvent(K paramK, V paramV, int paramInt, E paramE);
} --- I was forced to replace the typed parameters with - Object!!!!

Comment: I've also had this problem, but in a different context. I'm trying to compile an OSGI (v4.2) application and the compiler blows up telling me the classes aren't generic, when they are, in fact, generic.

Comment: Accidentally hit return in that last comment...I was going to go on and say that I read somewhere when I looked at this problem before (I can't find where that is, though!) it said something to the effect that the OSGI jars were compiled for binary 1.4 compatibility and that when the compiler loaded the class file, it say the 1.4 compatibility and dumped the generics information. If the files were compiled against a minimum 1.5 binary target, then the generics information was preserved and things worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding discrepancies when reading a certification book for SCJP based on JDK 1.6, and, trying to write (copy and paste) code, compiling within JDK 1.7.

Perhaps, I am making the same mistakes all over, however they seem hard to comprehend.  For example see my posts at http://www.coderanch.com/forums/posts/list/80/467890#2679297.  I am not an expert, however, I find the curriculum of Angelika Langer (http://www.angelikalanger.com/Publications.html), to be appealing for consulting, given the tutorials available on the website relating to Java Generics.

What is your advice on the matter?